# Excel Function for Domain Names

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Could someone help me out, I need a excel function to take the domain name.

```
For Eg

1)en.wikipedia.org    
2)forum.diyaudiocart.com    
3)us.wow.com    
4)madurai.tomatotail.com    
5)healthyliving.natureloc.co.in    


Required Output

1)wikipedia.org    
2)diyaudiocart.com    
3)wow.com    
4)tomatotail.com    
5)natureloc.co.in
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code? If so, could you post it?

Comment: Why in Excel? In DHTML/Javascript there is `document.location.hostname` but that aplies to the current (resolved) URL. If you look at your number 5, how is a function to know that India has subdivided itself into sub domains? `co.in` would seem a proper top-level domain name.

Comment: @sandeeep if the answer is what you were looking for, please accept it as answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=RIGHT(cell,(LEN(cell)-SEARCH(".",cell)))
```

where *cell* is the cell with the complete address you whant to trim

Comment: Hey EttoreP,

Thanks a lot, it works:)

Regards,
-SM

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer with a click in the "v" symbol under the number on the left of the answer.

Comment: if you give input as google.com only, it will output com , which is not correct. need to handle this also